# Can a QString be shared between two Qt containers without being deep-copied?

Tags: qt, containers, qstring, copy-on-write

Say I have the code below.

```
    QSet<QString> set;
    QList<QString> list;
    QString str("hello");

    set.insert(str);
    list.append(str);
```

Question: Is the QString deep-copied into the two containers, or is the QString now shared among the three variables (i.e., a single copy of "hello" in the QString with a reference count of 3)?

Comment: Since QString is [implcitly shared](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/implicit-sharing.html) - no there is no copy until you call a non-const function on the QString.

Comment: The code above does QString content sharing until that QString was modified buf after modified it becomes copy-on-write for that specific container item.

Comment: chehrlic, in the QSet, the QString is a key. Does that make a difference?